# C# SQL select from [tablename] error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, localdb

I'm trying to execute a simple SQL select statement, however the SQL Server table I'm trying to access can have a table name that includes numbers on the first position, spaces, SQL keywords etc.

If I understand correctly, putting square brackets around the table name should allow me to do this, but it doesn't seem to be working.

`tr_projekt` is a string that holds the name of the table I want to access - for example, with `tr_projekt = "4test"` I'm getting

> Incorrect syntax error near 4

followed by a `System.NullReferenceException`.

For regular table names, like `tr_projekt = "test"`, it works correctly.

```
string type = "";
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);            
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT DisplayType FROM [" + tr_projekt + "]");
command.Connection = conn;                           
conn.Open();             
type = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
conn.close();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you try this once : "SELECT DisplayType FROM '[' + tr_projekt + ']'"

Comment: Cannot reproduce. A table named 4Test when enclosed in square brackets could be read using your code

Comment: I don' t know what value tr_projekt holds but did you try [DatabaseName].[dbo].[TableName]. I don't think just adding the table name will be enough.

Comment: This may not be related to your issue, but it's something you should fix. [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). You *must* make sure you dispose of it properly to avoid problems with your application. The easiest way to do that is to wrap your command in a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx).

Comment: @AlokGupta putting '[' and ']' gives incorrect syntax error near [

Comment: @JeffJaffery I tried SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT DisplayType FROM ["+conn.Database+"].[dbo].["+ tr_projekt + "]"); but I still get the same error as before

Comment: @mason thanks for the heads up, I generally encase SqlCommands in using, but this is more of a test case I'm trying to resolve, so excuse me if the code is a bit messy :)

Comment: Can we see the attributes in your connectionString, which also might help explain how to write your sql string. Or you can ditch the  '[]' brackets altogether and try dbo.TableName, in your case appended to tr_projekt, or without dbo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must create the connection string and querys helping from string.Format(string,params[]), will be cleanest way to see what are you doing.

Put a break point on:`command.Connection=conn;` then point at command and find the property commandText to see your sql command copy and try to run the command directly your dbms (sql server managment as i can see,dbvisualizer, mysql workbench or any other you using)

Here there are some rules in table names:
n SQL Server 2012, an object name can be up to 128 characters long.

Nonquoted identifier names must follow these rules:

- The first character must be alphanumeric, an underscore (_), an at sign (@), or a number sign (#).
- Subsequent characters can include alphanumeric characters, an underscore, an at (@) sign, a number sign, or a dollar sign.
- Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.

I think you could be missing some quotes or double quotes, try to acomplish make a query directly to db and then use as a model to make your query in c# code.

Comment: Thank you, you pushed me in the right direction, I tried to execute the statement directly against a test database, which worked, so I went step-by-step debugging, and I was really missing a square bracket in another statement earlier in my code (I completely missed that), which ultimately led to a crash in my posted code.